# Add asterisks next to the value where there are any duplicate instances

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to merge the tables together and put asterisks next to any `COLOR` and `WORK` that are duplicate instances with the same person only.

`TABLE1`:

```
NAME     COLOR     WORK
----------------------------
Jane     purple    eDisco
Gianne   Red       Fashion
Daya     pink      Education
Sheryl   pink      eDisco
Jannelle green     Fasion
```

`TABLE2`:

```
NAME     COLOR     WORK
----------------------------------
Jane     gray      Technology
Gianne   Orange    Sales
Daya     Purple    Education
Sheryl   pink      FM
Jannelle pink      Fashion
```

SQL:

```
SELECT *
INTO TEMP_MERGEALL
FROM TABLE1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * TABLE2 
ORDER BY NAME
GO

;WITH CTE as 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COLOR ORDER BY COLOR) AS rno,
        COLOR
    FROM TEMP_MERGEALL
    )
UPDATE CTE 
SET COLOR = COLOR +' ***** '
WHERE rno = 2
GO

;WITH CTE as 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Work ORDER BY Work) AS rno,
        Work
    FROM TEMP_MERGEALL
    )
UPDATE CTE 
SET WORK = WORK +' ***** '
WHERE rno = 2
GO
```

I get this (it's only recognizing the duplicate instances of COLOR and WORK and not by the name)

```
Daya        pink           Education
Daya        purple         Education *****
Gianne      red            Fashion
Gianne      orange         Sales
Jane        purple *****   eDisco
Jane        gray           Technology
Jannelle    green          Fashion *****
Janelle     pink *****     Fashion
Sheryl      pink           FM
Sheryl      pink           eDisco
```

HOWEVER, I am looking to have my results as this (add the asterisks next to `COLOR` and `WORK` when there is duplicate grouped by the name)

```
Daya        pink           Education
Daya        purple         Education *****
Gianne      red            Fashion
Gianne      orange         Sales
Jane        purple         eDisco
Jane        gray           Technology
Janelle     green          Fashion 
Janelle     pink           Fashion *****
Sheryl      pink           FM
Sheryl      pink *****     eDisco
```

Any thoughts? I'm not sure where I add the `GROUP BY Name` to make the script work.

Comment: I don't know SQL server, but if it's anything like Oracle I suspect you'd need to add `Name` to your partition, not as a `group by`.  Also, if it's possible to have more than duplicate for a person, you might want to change `WHERE rno = 2` to `WHERE rno >= 2`

Comment: Thank you very MUCH for this information. It worked!!! I added the NAME in my partitions and the end results came out successful.